# Hestia Panel Setup Cron job for Laravel8?

Tags: cron, laravel-8

I am using Hestia Control Panel in Laravel8. I want to set up a cron job locally it's working fine but on Control Panel in the Command section it's not working anyone has an idea about this? what Command or how should I write Command

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to create a cron command. everyone is using the c panel but I am using a Hestia Control Panel so not able to find any example with the cron command. tried solution getting for c panel but it not working

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding website url as cron https://mydeskcare.com/cron.php

use below line of code

/usr/bin/wget -O- https://mydeskcare.com/cron.php

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).